# How to check if mouse is over selected area in mschart

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

In my WinForms application I have Chart control with those settings:

```
chartArea.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
chartArea.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
chartArea.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
```

where `chartArea` is main (and only) ChartArea object in my Chart control.

What I am trying to do is posibility of selecting area (it is possible already), and when mouse is over this area, if I left click chart cotrol inside that selected area, I wan't it too zoom in.

First problem here is how to detect if I am over selected area ? with `chart.HitTest()` i can get `HitTestResult.PointIndex` field value and compare it with selection range. But this only works, if mouse is exactly over DataPoint. So it *doesn't work* for `SeriesChartType.FastLine` which I am using.

If this gets somehow solved, next will be problem with selection cancelation after mouse click (before `Click` or `MouseXXX` events are called).

---

**SOLVED**

I've found `axis.PixelPositionToValue()` method, which gives me every info I need, because from MouseMove event arguments I have pixel position.
For click events problem I'll write another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.bigresource.com/VB-Using-MsChart-MouseOver-Event-to-display-the-contents-of-array-that-populated-chart-ydWJntrg8c.html

Though this is VB.NET, the concept is the same. I think.

Comment: Old solution written in VB which I don't know (but probably I understand whats written there). Control I am using is available in VS from 2010 version (I'm sorry for my mistake, because I wrote MSChart). Alhough your solution wasn't what I've been looking for, this helped me to find PixelPositionToValue() method, which solves my problem ;) so thanks anyway.